# Cant insert attachment to a page

Tags: 2013

We have had the following issue on our SP 2013 Farm in our intranet.

WHen users creates a new page, and insert an attachment to the page, nothing appears, the file is indeed uploaded, but the attachment does not appear, they have to go to add link and manually add the link to the page.

We have december CU, can someone reproduce it too? 
When we change to seattle.master we still experience the same issue which means that is not custom branding or custom js related.

Thanks

Comment: Good question. I've tried this in my environment, which is an Enterprise Wiki, and have no issues using the *Upload File* control in the Ribbon and getting a link in the SitePage. I wonder if I may be using a different Site Template than you? Which Site template do you use?

Comment: its: BaseTemplateID="39" BaseTemplateName="CMSPUBLISHING"

Comment: When I create a new site using that templete, it looks like a 2010 site, even if i specify ´-CompatibilityLevel 15´. I wonder if the site template is fully functional in SP 2013.

Comment: Yes it was a migration from a 2010 site, can you reproduce the issue there?

Comment: The only thing I can do is to upload the document to the pages library. I find no way to add the document as attchement to an excisting page.

Comment: Can you create new web app and try add attachment?

Comment: @AlexanderUlmaskulov why would that solve it? do you have something on mind?

Comment: In the past I had a problem. I have not decided. But it was gone in a new Web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at the comments i could safely say that the template that your using is for 2010 as benny noted. In 2010 that capability wasnt available to attach attachments to the page. You have to use a webpart that displays attachments from a document library where it stores the attachments.

If you were to use a 2013 template than you would have it ootb as standard. If you need to have the attachments on the page than you need to change the template to a 2013 template and not a 2010 template or use a webpart that displays the attachments as noted above (due to 2010 template being used)